# How to have UITableViewCell reference objects in an array?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array of objects that have multiple instance variables (`name`, `address`, `number`, etc). I also have a `UITableViewController` whose table view is populated with the `name` variable of each of these objects.

I have also created a `DetailViewController` that should display the rest of the information held by these objects when that objects' designated cell is selected with `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. The problem is, these cells only have references to the cell's objects' `name` variable.

How should I go about fixing this problem? Would I need to subclass the cell so that I could give each cell a reference to the entire object? or is there an easier way?

This is my current `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"listingName"];
    return cell;
}
```

update: it just occured to me that I could grab the row number from `indexPath` and grab the designated object from the array. Would this be more viable?

Comment: Subclass it and declare a property?

Comment: You certainly don't subclass the cell to get a reference to the entire object -- cells are for displaying data, not for supplying data. Your final sentence mentions the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can just use `[listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get the selected object, and pass that to the detail view controller.

(You should never try to use the table view cells as data source.)

Comment: and if you really want to go all `nu skool` you could do `listings[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are displaying the listings directly from their array position, you get them out again the same way once you pressed the row.

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` just do `[listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get the object in question and send it over to the `DetailViewController`